# ProgressView Issue in Android?

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar, uiprogressview

I am using [this](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView) Example to Create ProgressView and It work fine. But In My SplashScreenActivity How can I Stop the ProgressView  when the AsyncTask is done.And I can't found how to Stop this ProgressView.
Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: there are  methods like stopSpinning() and clearAnimation() you can use them

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can stop the progress view!

Our only chance is to hide it with

```
progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Then In Background it will running ?

Comment: It's only animated if it's visible, so no it won't be using any resources